# Closing a window in python 3.7.2 with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've made a program in python with Tkinter that allows you to free draw and choose different colors. I decided to make a button that would close the window instead of clicking the exit button in the top right corner. My question is how do I make the window close when the button is pressed?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What approach have you tried? Please provide some source code so others may help, this site is not for such general questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a main loop for your application, then you can use the `.destroy()` method to release all the resources associated with the window and close the application. You call this method within the command function for your button like so:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(side=LEFT)
button = Button(frame, text="Exit", command=exit)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()

def exit():
    root.destroy()
```

That should close your window. Optionally, the `destroy()` method may also be used at the end of your main loop if the X button of your application won't close the window immediately.

See these examples for more info:

- http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.destroy-method
- http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-again.htm